# Is there any way I could overlap another css?

Tags: css, overlapping

Is there any way I could overlap another css?!
For example, I have my search bar on top of the shopping cart and if I hover over the Search bar on accident then my shopping cart disappears since it's the top layer/ first layer. Here's an image. Is there a way to fix this in CSS where the shopping cart is the first layer not second? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Please provide your code and live link in issue.

Comment: fiddle will be nice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its basically a `z-index` Problem

you should give `z-index` greater value to your shopping cart css and **less**  `z-index` value to your search box **div**

The z-index property in CSS controls the vertical stacking order of elements that overlap. As in, which one appears as if it is physically closer to you. z-index only effects elements that have a position value other than static (the default).

**HTML**

```
<div class="a"></div>
   <div class="b"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.a {
    background:red;
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    z-index:2;
        position:relative;    

}

.b {
    background:green;
    height: 50px;
    left: 20px;
    position: relative;
    top: -30px;
    width: 100px;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Evnmm/6/)

Comment: I tried z-index before and it didn't work. Then I finally saw your post and figured it out. I did the complete opposite all this time giving the value 1 as thinking it'll be the first layer. The demo wasn't necessary but thanks for the advice "you should give z-index greater value to your shopping cart css and less z-index value to your search box div"

Comment: Thank you, Shailender Arora!